# Excel warning : File is in different format than specified by the file extension

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, content-type

In my application, I am using apache  POI 3.8 for report generation.

The system is working fine and its generating report in xls format.

But when I open the xls file it given me warning before opening the file.

[image]

And here is the response type I am using...

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");         
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+xlsFileName+".xls");
```

I also tried with ...

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+xlsFileName+".xls");
 response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

But the problem still exist. Here in both of the case If I use file extension as ".xlsx" then Its not giving any warning and works fine.

So can anyone suggest me why it gives warning for MS-Excel 2003 format ??

Comment: Maybe your xls is not really xls but is in fact HTML pretending to be xls?  In that case the message is due to extension hardening in Office.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apache POI uses HSSFWorkbook object for creating xls files and XSSFWorkbook object for xlsx files. Please check what object you used for creating xls.

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

Comment: So is there any common interface to create both xls and xlsx file ??

Comment: Workbook is a common interface for both xls and xlsx. Check the above link which contains the code samples.

Comment: ohk..I had used Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(); so I was generating xlsx file but the extension was xks. So I was getting above mentioned warning. I replaced it with Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(); Now its not giving any warning and working fine. Thanks for the reply :)